# Border around ul square with css

Tags: html, css

I have simple `<ul><li>` list which is `type="square"`. What I'm trying to do is to make this square white but with black border only around the square.

The reason is because my page background color is white and the square isn't visible.

I'm sure that is something easy but can't figured it out. Here is what I've tried so far

```css
ul li {
    color: white;
}
li::before {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li span {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul type="square">
    <li>
        <span>Item 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item 2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the square isn't visible.

Comment: it is because you use  color: white; in li tag. so change this.

Comment: If I don't use `color: white;` it's become black. I want to be white but with black border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of  `list-style-type` use Psuedo element for li and style it to look like square and add border

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}

ul li {
   // color: white;
   position:relative ;
}
ul li::before {
       content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    top: 3px;
}
ul li span {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Item 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item 2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Ivan welcome.please accept/upvote if my answer helped

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
ul li {
    color: white;
}
```

with this

```
ul li {
    color: black;
}
```

or with any color what you need, as long as the color not same as the background

Answer (score 0):

You can't target the existing list item bullet point, but you can modify your before element to create a new custom bullet with the style you want.

Unfortunately, there is no way I know of to get the position of the bullet point, so you'll have to just choose a position that looks good to you using the 'left' property.

```css
ul li {
    color: white;
}
li::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -18px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul li span {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul type="square">
    <li>
        <span>Item 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item 2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode symbols in content property of `::before` pseudoelement. See [UTF-8 Geometric Shapes](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp) to find required symbol and convert that code to HEX. For your case the `\20e3` is fit:

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
   }
   li::before {
    content: "\20e3";
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
   }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```